# Horizontal scrolling of content of unknown width

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a content div that shows a long line of text. I want the content to be contained in a wrapper div that will have a fixed height and the option to scroll horizontally if the content is longer than the wrapper div's width.

As I see it, there are two solutions for I want to do:

1. `white-space: nowrap;`, which feels a bit hacky in practice. Run the snippet I attached and you'll see what I mean; the background doesn't extend to the edge of the text because the text is overflowing its intended boundaries.
2. Set a width, which gets the text to do what I want but doesn't work when I don't know what text will be in the content div. This isn't how vertical scrolling works anyways; I don't need to guess what overall height I need (or set a ridiculously high height) in order to activate vertical scrolling.

What I'm essentially looking for is a way to get the browser to do horizontally what it already does vertically. If this is not possible (and I don't think it is), are there any better solutions than the two I've explored?

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.content {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: overflow-x:scroll; any good ?

Comment: @Billy Doesn't seem that way. It forces a scrollbar to appear but that bar but doesn't force the text past the boundary of the wrapper div.

Comment: I think your question needs to be clearer.You want to force the text outside the wrapper, or you don't and want a scrollbar ? You need to rewrite the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `display:inline-block` to your `.content` div

http://jsfiddle.net/9f1y5q1r/

CSS

```
 .wrapper {
     position: relative;
     background-color: green;
     width: 50%;
     overflow: auto;
     overflow-y: hidden;
     padding-bottom: 50px;
 }
 .content {
     background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
     white-space: nowrap;
     display:inline-block;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to take care of it. Thanks for taking the time.